# Django, Twitter Streaming API ( using Twython or other library ) related

Tags: django, twitter

may i know if anyone has a working example using Django with Twitter's Streaming API?
It would be great if the example is using Twython library.

Or, may I know if there's a generic method in catching the live streaming data from Twitter's streaming API? I have some issues in understanding how do i work with live streaming data.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of Twython.

Currently, Twython doesn't support the Streaming API. I'm in the process of adding it in due to user demand (previously, contrary to popular belief, nobody ever asked me for it - go figure).

In the meantime, I'd advocate using Tweepy for any Streaming API needs, as my time is spread a bit thin. Twython will have Streaming in the near future, though, and then you'd better come back over!